# c++/cx passing value struct by reference

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cx

"If you have a value type as a function or method parameter, it is normally passed by value. For larger objects, this can cause a performance problem. In Visual Studio2013 and earlier, value types in C++/CX were always passed by value. In Visual Studio 2015 and later, you can pass value types by reference or by value."

That did not work for me, using value_struct& in a function signature had the compiler issue the:

> **Error** C3987   'Set': signature of public member contains native type value_struct&... Works without the reference, Visual Studio 2015

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work like this:

```
public interface class MyDelegate {
    void MyDelegateMethod(Platform::String^ str,
        Windows::Foundation::Point *point);
}
```

.. and in the C# delegate implementation:

```
public void MyDelegateMethod(string str, out Point p) { ... }
```

It's mentioned in the MS page on this stuff (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699861.aspx):

> You can also use a pointer symbol (*) to pass a value type by reference. The behavior with respect to callers in other languages is the same (callers in C# use the ref keyword), but in the method, the type is a pointer to the value type.